# Javascript escape all single quotes in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string

I want to store html in json and for that i stringify the html.

Problem is that I can't replace all single quotes.

This is my code:

```
<div id="myHtml">Men's and Women's something.</div>
```

and js:

```
function save(){
    item = {}
    dataTemplate = []
    item['html'] = $('#myHtml').html().replace(/'/g,"\'"); // not working
    // tried with .replace(/'/g,"\\'"); but I don't want two \\
    // this is broken .replace(/'\/g,"\\'")
    dataTemplate.push(item);
    alert(JSON.stringify(dataTemplate));
}
```

How else can I do it?

Comment: You have to double the backslash in the replacement string.

Comment: why do you even need to escape them?

Comment: Right what you *really* need to worry about are double-quote characters.

Comment: What's with the first `.replace.`? Or is this just something I'm not familiar with?

Comment: @Santi edited, thanks.

Comment: `$('#myHtml').html().replace(/'/g,"\\'");`

Comment: 1. `item` is **not** JSON (nor is `dataTemplate`), 2. you don't need to replace/escape single quotes if you store them in an object. What is your actual problem?

Comment: I am pushing dataTemplate into a form where I store it as json. My problem is the replace, not the json and `.replace(/'/g,"\\'")` returns this for me: **Men\\'s and..**

Comment: The question of Jaromanda is still not answered. You don't have to escape single quotes. Why do you still think you need to do so?

Comment: ^^ I agree .. The need to escape them should not be in the JSON -- I can see if you're then using PHP and storing to a database, but then there's a whole other list of clean-up you need to do before storing it in the database.

Comment: because i get this in the end `[{"html":"<a href=\"http://google.com\" target=\"_blank\">Men's</a>"}]` and It's broken.

Comment: working on frontside and sending this to aspx, dunno nothing how that work, but I only know that need that scaped else I get error

Answer (score 1):

Issue is not replace, it's how JSON.stringify treats a backslash. So if you do your replacement after stringify it'll work.

For e.g.

```js
function save(){
    item = {}
    dataTemplate = []
    item['html'] = $('#myHtml').html();
    dataTemplate.push(item);
    a = JSON.stringify(dataTemplate);
    a = a.replace(/'/g,"\\'");
    //alert(a);
    console.log(a);
}

save();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="myHtml">Men's and Women's something.</div>
```